# Universal search Acumatica does not work with dot symbol on the Windows server

Tags: c#, .net, iis, acumatica

I added an alternative id to the universal search, and now I can search for an element using an alternative id, but if there is a dot character in the alternative id, the universal search does not return results on the Window server, but it works correctly on the local server. I tried using the rebuilt file but it didn’t help. and looked universal search works with a description and if there is a point in it then the corrector returns the result. What should I do to make the universal search work with a point on the Windows server?

```
        [PXRemoveBaseAttribute(typeof(PXSearchableAttribute))]
        [PXSearchable(PX.Objects.SM.SearchCategory.IN, "{0}: {1}",
        new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.itemType),
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD) },
        new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.descr),
            typeof(InventoryItemExt.usrAlternateIDs) },
        NumberFields = new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.inventoryCD),
            typeof(InventoryItemExt.usrAlternateIDs) },
        Line1Format = "{0}{1}{2}",
        Line1Fields = new Type[] {
            typeof(INItemClass.itemClassCD),
            typeof(INItemClass.descr),
            typeof(InventoryItem.baseUnit) },
        Line2Format = "{0}",
        Line2Fields = new Type[] {
            typeof(InventoryItem.descr) },
        WhereConstraint = typeof(Where<Current<InventoryItem.itemStatus>,
            NotEqual<InventoryItemStatus.unknown>>)
        )]
        public Guid? NoteID { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asked the support case to Acumatica and got that message.
The dash character is used as a separator in standard fulltext search on SQL server. So you receive the result that has some of parts of the item specified. Nothing we can do about.